# Can we delete a version from the catalog or copy an older version to make it the latest version?

Tags: here-olp

We are just starting to work with publishing to DataService catalogs, we use `data-client` library for this. Our team has decided to have VersionedLayer in the catalog because that fits our use case best. Our product is a pipeline of 5 components and our application is the first. We publish our output to a data service catalog and the next component consumes from it. In case something goes wrong and corrupts the data downstream, we want to be able to go back in time - like a good/stable version of the catalog. Is this possible with DataService catalogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catalog versions cannot be deleted but an older version can be read and then copied to a new version.